# how to copy List from one Service to another (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring

I have List in StudentService

`private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( new Student("1", "Lukasz", "Nowak", "Cicha 3", "1a"), new Student("2", "Tomasz", "Tomczyk", "Krakowska 13a", "1a"), new Student("3", "Grzegorz", "Adamiak", "Podkarpacka 8", "2b"), new Student("4", "Klaudia", "Kurcz", "Warszawska 13", "2b")));`

and i want copy some of elements to PresentService and add a present
I tried to do 

`List<Presents> presents = new ArrayList<Student>()`
but I got only errors

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: Error:(22, 34) java: incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList<pl.pgs.homework.schoolapi.students.Student> cannot be converted to java.util.List<pl.pgs.homework.schoolapi.presents.Present>

Comment: Indeed, you cannot add `Student` objects to a `List` of type `Present`, they are not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Presents> presents = new ArrayList<Student>()
```

This statement will not compile.

You variable definition is expecting objects of type Presents but you gave it a list of Student.

The easiest solution would be

```
List<Presents> presents = students.stream().map((student) -> new Present(student)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And create a constructor in Presents class

```
public Presents(Student student) {
   //Create your present object as you would want to here
   //For example if you wanted name
   this.name = student.getName();
}
```